# custom permalink's rewrite rule for page id

Tags: plugin-development, permalinks

I am using WP 3.2.1.

I try to do permalink like: /en/1/some-string. Structure is: %lang%/%pageID%/%some random string%

So I add a rewrite rule:

```
function  nw_lang_addRewrite($aRules) {
    $_aRules["(en|lt|ru)/(\d+)(/.*)?$"] = 'index.php?p=$matches[2]&lang=$matches[1]';

    $aRules = $_aRules + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
}
```

add a lang tag:

```
function nw_lang_addQuery($vars) {
    $aVars[] = "lang";
    return $aVars;
}
```

Buf if user go to http://www.somesite.com/en/17/2-Pork.html he dont see page with ID = 17.

$wp_query is:

```
WP_Query Object (
    [query_vars] => Array
        (
            [lang] => en
            [error] => 
            [m] => 0
            [p] => 0

            .....

            [static] => 
            [pagename] => 
            [page_id] => 0
            [paged] => 0

       ....

    [is_single] => 
    [is_preview] => 
    [is_page] => 
    [is_paged] => 

    ...

    [queried_object] => 
    [queried_object_id] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem. I needed change function parameter name to "$aVars".

```
function nw_lang_addQuery($avars)
```